# PropertyGrid - Collection Edition / Wrapper

Tags: c#, winforms, propertygrid

I have a complex kind of property I want to edit in a PropertyGrid.

```
interface IInterface{}

abstract class Base : IInterface{}

class A : Base{}
class B : Base{}
```

These class represent what can be stored in the property (The content of these class does not matter).

```
// The Property to be displayed in the PropertyGrid
class Property
{
    List<Base> MyListOfObjects {get;set;}        
}
```

I managed to create a derived class of `System.ComponentModel.Design.CollectionEditor` which allows me to add different kind of datas, using `[Editor(typeof(MyCollectionEditor), typeof(UITypeEditor))]` attribute in the collection property.

```
class MyCollectionEditor : CollectionEditor
{
    public MyCollectionEditor(Type type) : base(type)
    {            
    }

    #region Overrides of CollectionEditor
    protected override Type[] CreateNewItemTypes()
    {
        base.CreateNewItemTypes();
        // [EDIT assembly, see below]
        var types = (from t in Assembly.GetAssembly(typeof(IInterface)).GetTypes()
                     where t.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof (IInterface)) && !t.IsAbstract
                     select t).ToArray();
        return types;
    }

    protected override Type CreateCollectionItemType()
    {
        return typeof(A); // 1st problem
    }
}
```

- First Problem: The only solution I found to be able to edit the objects is to give a concrete child class type in `CreateCollectionItemType()`. Why? How to avoid that?
- Second Problem: I now want to use a wrapper to give this property to the `propertyGrid` item. Instead of having the property attributes (`[Category("General")]` for instance) in the model, I want to put them in a wrapper.

It works fine for everything but the collection. 
Here is how I did it:

```
class abstract WrapperBase<T>
{
    T WrappedObject{get;set;}
}
class PropertyWrapper:WrapperBase<Property>
{
    List<Base> MyListOfObjects
    {
        get{return WrappedObject.MyListOfObjects;}
        set{WrappedObject.MyListOfObjects=value;}
    }
}
```

With this, the collection editor won't let me add objects to this Collection, and the dropdown that was available to add a specific kind of object is gone.

Any idea? Thanks in advance!

---

**[EDIT]**

The second part of the problem is solved: Since the wrapper is located in another assembly, I was not looking in the right place for the implementations of IInterface.

Answer (score 0):

CreateNewItemTypes is good. in CreateCollectionItemType return the base type. i think that should work.

Comment: I tried that, but then the PropertyGrid does not provide the fields that are specific to derived types.